# Unbalanced HTML tags confuse keyboard shortcuts for wmd editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Hardly a real problem, but maybe a code review reveals more: when using Google Chrome and having unbalanced HTML tags in a post (tags for which no matching opening or closing tag is found) then hitting Ctrl-B or Ctrl-I (or Command-B or Command-I) somewhere in the post, inserts additional brackets.

Like (when not in a code block):

```
<pre>
Now hitting Ctrl-B (both below or above the unbalanced tag), gets me:
>**strong text**>
instead of
**strong text**
```

On my Mac, this only happens in Chrome, not in Safari nor Firefox. It only occurs for *allowed* tags, like `<pre>`, `<b>` or `<i>`, but not for `<u>` or `<blink>`. The toolbar buttons do not get confused. When the unbalanced tags are in code blocks or within backticks, then all is fine too.

(Chrome 9.0.597.107 and 10.0.648.127 on latest OS X.)

Comment: Maybe related: [<pre> tags seem to break imgur images in edit preview?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/pre-tags-seem-to-break-imgur-images-in-edit-preview/84750#84750): when starting to type `<b` for `<b>..</b>` images might disappear. Not limited to *allowed* HTML tags though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed this one previously. Seems very likely that this is pretty much the same thing as [Why am I getting undefined text in the Answer text box?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101048/why-am-i-getting-undefined-text-in-the-answer-text-box/101062#101062), in which case this shouldn't be happening anymore. I for one can't reproduce it. Can you confirm this is fixed?

Comment: Seems fine indeed.