# Formatting toolbar in IE9 scrolls editor back to start of post

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, markdown, internet-explorer-9

When editing a post in Internet Explorer 9, and applying formatting to the selected text with a click on one of the toolbar's formatting buttons, the editor scrolls back to the start of the post.

Result: the selection is not visible anymore.

The selection is not changed and hás the new formatting tags around. Maybe it has something to do with [this slightly related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83250/formatting-toolbar-does-not-work-properly-in-ie-9)?

All other browsers I have tested do not expose this bug: Opera 11.5, Safari 5.0.5, FF 5.0, Chrome 12.0, all on Windows 7/64. Even more weird; IE7 and IE8 manage a toolbar click also just fine.

For now, two simple workarounds:

- use the keyboard arrows to force the cursor scroll back in view, or
- do not use the toolbar buttons altogether; instead, use the applicable keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed slightly related to that other question. As I explain there, in IE the current state of the input area has to be saved somewhere when you click a button and later be restored.

What we didn't save so far was the scroll position of the input area. This broke with IE9, because (unlike IE8) it now supports `element.selectionStart` etc.; hence we're not using IE-specific code in all places anymore, and the non-IE-specific code also needs the scroll position.

In the next build, this position will also be saved and restored.