# <pre> tags seem to break imgur images in edit preview?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, imgur, pre

I answered this question (links to my answer) and uploaded a couple of screenshots:

> [Connection between MSSQL and PHP 5.3.5 on IIS is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425322/connection-between-mssql-and-php-5-3-5-on-iis-is-not-working/5432118#5432118)

When I was composing the answer one of the uploaded screenshots wouldn't appear in the preview properly:

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5432118/edit ([screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm1zp.png))

[Yi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) on chat had a look and it noted that removing the `<pre>` tags resolves this and that `showdown.js` (?) might not be handling raw HTML markup properly?

**Update:**

Arjan also points out in his answer that using sole `<--` without a corresponding inside the `<pre></pre>` tags is also breaking something. See below.

Comment: When using `<pre>` (rather than indenting 4 spaces), one needs to HTML encode some characters manually to ensure a browser does not interpret it. This includes the `<` and `>` characters. So, to show the `<--` without any issues, one would better type `&lt;--` instead.

Comment: I missed this report. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89734/mysterious-butt, which was arguably more interesting :)

Comment: @balpha - yep that's a way more interesting variant :)

Answer (score 3):

It's lowercasing the image URL, somehow, and https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqdjc.jpg is not the same as https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqDjc.jpg.

For this specific case, this is caused by the non-encoded `<--` below (which should read `&lt;--` instead):

```
<pre>
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll   <-- optional
</pre>
```

This also breaks [other parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LupcO.png) of the preview.

However, I've noticed that while editing, images might temporarily not render either when typing an opening tag somewhere above an image, and/or when opening and closing tags don't match yet? Like as soon as one has typed `<b` for `<b>...</b>`, an unrelated image might no longer show.

So the bug report still stands, I'd say.

Comment: Some day, the lowercase image URL will in fact exist, but be a different image. That might have been fun!

Comment: LOL...I hadn't spotted that case mattered. Also good catch on the <--, I missed that. Have fudged for now.

Comment: now here - [Mysterious Butt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89734)