# Mysterious Butt

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, images

I was attempting to answer a question today on SO and include some screenshots to help illustrate what I was talking about.  Everything was fine until I went to upload my fourth image.  Here is what the post screen looked like before I selected to upload:
[image]

Once I pressed the Image button I got [this **potentially NSFW** image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scqh9.png)

This was very surprising.  Until today I haven't been able to see post images as they were uploaded (corporate blocking), so maybe this has been around a while. But based on what I've now seen, perhaps the corporate blocking was for the best?

Is this a bug or are we trying to fit in better on the internet by increasing our butt to post ratio?

Comment: Three links and you are mooned. ;-).

Comment: This looks like a very weird imgur hiccup. What is the butt's URL? And congratulations on creating the `buttocks` tag!

Comment: The most important part is missing here: What is the content of that post (which, as it seems, was never posted); in particular the URLs? Also, what @Pekka said.

Comment: @balpha I was in the middle of making this post when I saw the Butt. I have since finished the answer and you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741684/sharepoint-template-bug-workflow-fix-not-working/5874467#5874467

Comment: How can we help him earn the taxonomist badge?

Comment: @theChrisKent: Thanks. Do you also have the URL of the butt image? I'm asking purely for scientific reasons.

Comment: What a *bizarre* mix-up. This will have its place in the annals  of Stack Overflow. (no pun intended)

Comment: I think I have a new hobby. k3yku == boring SO screenshot. k3ykU == toy gun.

Comment: +1 for question title.

Comment: @balpha you fixed the preview to be case sensitive now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes, it's fixed in the code; it's not deployed yet though.

Comment: @Chris - little sense of humor, eh?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - no, someone suggested an inappropriate edit to the tag wiki, so I thought I'd remove the temptation ;)

Comment: ["If you're doing a text search in this document for the word 'butts,' the good news is that it's here, but the bad news is that it only appears in this unrelated quote." - Randall Munroe](https://xkcd.com/1942/)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[YOU's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89734/mysterious-butt/89740#89740) excellent work and the OP's detailed screenshots made it pretty easy to get to the bottom of this:

You'll note in the screenshot (the one that Daniel censored away) that the image definition is pretty broken; you see something like `![![![bla][3]][` etc. This utterly wrong markdown causes the creation of unbalanced HTML tags, so the tag balancer kicks in. The actual bug is in the tag balancer, which lowercases the content it doesn't remove.

This is fixed in the next build.

Until then, to reproduce: Just [go to the edit screen for the post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5874467/edit) and insert a lonely `<b>` at the beginning.

Comment: "... get to the *bottom* of this:" You're so cheeky.

Comment: @gnostradamus: There's nothing funny here. This was a simple string manipulation issue.

Comment: @badp: "posterior"ity, you mean.

Comment: Please don't be anal about word choices here. Let's put this matter behind us and move on.

Comment: This is the most fanny thing I've read today on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Kudos to balpha and YOU for their keen ASSessment and diligent ASSistance in addressing this crack in the system. You two are real ASSets to SO. There was clearly a hole in the code, and someone will need to keep a [brown] eye on it.

Comment: All of this fits together **way** to neatly to set up an endless well of puns, so I remain *highly* sceptical.

Answer (score 91):

Well, its a preview's lower case issue between

[http://i.imgur.com/jVCUe.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVCUe.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiORE.jpg

<sup>(Meanwhile, `stack` has been [inserted into many Stack Exchange image URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734), somehow making the original URLs rot away.)</sup>

Comment: YOU's brilliant powers of deduction win once again! You should work for the police or something. Good stuff.

Comment: That's some mighty fine police work there, YOU

Comment: This is actually extremely hilarious `:)`