# Can we determine what the problem is with an imgur linked image?

Tags: discussion, imgur, broken-link

The original version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books/742009#742009) had an imgur image embedded in it ([original edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/742009/edit/0683cce6-d63c-4c67-9ed9-3e030e7c2216)). I've just now approved an edit which removed the imgur link because it was broken. I remembered seeing a bunch of meta posts regarding broken imgur links, so I revisited them, however possible alternatives of https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgsRW.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSMG8.png both still produce no result for the ID of that image (the URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCJEn.jpg produces an image of a cactus - but I'm sure that's not related to the answer, so it seems that the generated names for the uploaded images are not that unique).

[This meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104856/more-and-more-images-go-missing-can-the-cooked-html-be-rebuilt/117011#117011) from 2 days ago indicates that some work has been done to regenerate some HTML of old questions/answers, so possibly the problem lies with those changes.

Is there a way to determine whether that link was always broken, or whether some recent changes have broken it and it is possible to restore it?

Comment: (As for uppercasing Imgur URLs: see [Mysterious Butt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89734/mysterious-butt) and its earlier revisions. And oddly enough, http://i.imgur.com/Jsmg8.jpg has a cactus too!)

Comment: Off topic but amusing.. the URL is *case sensitive* - [example using your cactus URL changing one letter to small case](http://i.imgur.com/JSMg8.jpg) - this caused funny bug here some time ago. :)

Comment: @Arjan lol I was just looking for that butt issue, thanks!

Comment: By the way: I've never seen a `.jpg` Imgur URL generate a different image than its `.png` counterpart. But maybe Imgur does not convert JPEG into PNG (it surely does it the other way). So I'm kind of afraid Imgur is even re-using the URLs...? That would surely give one some nasty surprises...

Comment: @Sathya, interesting how those unbalanced asterisks in `[*http://i.imgur.com/JSMG8.png][3]*` were still in my version, *and* how that eventually seemed to render as valid HTML. Just curious: did you only edit to get rid of that emphasis, or did the links still somehow fail for you?

Comment: @Arjan Removed just the asterisks .. the images show the same behaviour as reported by the OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That image was [uploaded April 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/742009/1), before the official image upload was [introduced in August 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/). Hence, it was either uploaded to a private Imgur account, or to a free account. In both cases: apparently it has meanwhile [expired](https://imgur.com/faq#long) and is gone. Forever:

> How long do you keep the images?
>
> As long as images are getting at least 1 view every 6 months, they will stick around forever. After that, your image may be removed to create more space for newer images.

Comment: Fair enough, it's gone-burger then. Those links you've included should be good references for any further questions on the topic.